# Can I configure Chrome to stop warning about SHA-1 signed server certs?

Tags: tls, google-chrome

I'm using Chrome on a closed lab network.  I have no control over the servers I'm talking to, which use SHA1-signed certs for HTTPS.  Should they be using better certs? Of course, but I can't fix that. I just don't want to be bothered about it by my browser every time I open the sites.

Does Chrome have a flag or registry setting I could change that will stop warning about SHA1 certs?  Obviously this would be dangerous for use on the actual internet, but not every network is under threat of attack.

Comment: This may be of use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26388405/chrome-disable-ssl-checking-for-sites .

Comment: @iain - that switch does stop giving me cert errors, though it'd be nice to tell the difference between "uses a signature algorithm that nation-state could maybe spoof" and "presents a totally and obvious bogus cert"

Comment: this is a Chrome config question and not a security question

Comment: Does [this](https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors) help?

Comment: I can't test it right now but I will pass it along to our admins -- that sounds a lot like what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

For Mac Users
Run this command to create a plist file in XML format

```
cat >com.google.Chrome.plist <<POLICY
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
POLICY
```

Convert it to binary format using `plutil -convert binary1 com.google.Chrome.plist`

Move it into your system preferences `sudo cp com.google.Chrome.plist /Library/Preferences/`

Now visit `chrome://policy` and ensure `EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors` is set to `true` and has `OK` status (requires Chrome restart)

For windows update required in Registry

https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#EnableSha1ForLocalAnchors

Answer (score 1):

Disable the certificate warning using the below commands

Windows user - execute chrome.exe with the parameters as below or update the parameter to the Chrome shortcut

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests
```

Mac users - Execute the commands from the terminal

```
/Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome --ignore-certificate-errors --ignore-urlfetcher-cert-requests &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Max, take a look at the comments on the question -- the switch you specified ignores *all* cert errors, which technically solves the problem, but I'd like to keep warning about other errors while ignoring the SHA1 issue specifically.

Comment: Coderer, i have updated the steps for enabling the SHA-1 in the chrome://policy as new answer